# Oracle pl/sql order by case

Tags: oracle, sql-order-by

I need to arrange the below data in a particular format

```
Code    Qty
R   200
R   0
A   100
A   0
```

Required Output Format

```
 Active (A) with stock (Qty > 0)
 Reserve (R) with stock (Qty > 0)
 Active (A) without stock (Qty = 0)
 Reserve (R) without stock  (Qty = 0)
```

In above case

```
A 100
R 200
A 0
R 0
```

Please help me on this guys. i tried using case in order by but couldnt eventually figure out the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were right to try an `ORDER BY CASE`. The following will give the results you're looking for:

```
ORDER BY CASE
           WHEN CODE = 'A' AND QTY > 0 THEN 1
           WHEN CODE = 'R' AND QTY > 0 THEN 2
           WHEN CODE = 'A' AND QTY = 0 THEN 3
           WHEN CODE = 'R' AND QTY = 0 THEN 4
         END;
```

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=92ea66f66729cb28ad214d3939719d69)

Best of luck.

### EDIT

To accomplish the additional requirement mentioned by OP in a comment a second sort could be added to the `ORDER BY`:

```
ORDER BY CASE
           WHEN CODE = 'A' AND QTY > 0 THEN 1
           WHEN CODE = 'R' AND QTY > 0 THEN 2
           WHEN CODE = 'A' AND QTY = 0 THEN 3
           WHEN CODE = 'R' AND QTY = 0 THEN 4
         END ASC,
         CASE
           WHEN CODE = 'A' AND QTY > 0 THEN QTY
           ELSE NULL
         END DESC;
```

[new dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e73178cb1ec365b716dfcde5d883dc6f)

Comment: I have one more requirement here. If there are multiple 'A' codes e.g A 100 A 50 A 120,in that case, it needs to be in qty descending like A 120 A 100 A50

Answer (score 0):

For the specific data and requirement you presented, you don't really need a `case` expression. (Actually I am lying - `sign()` is a form of `case`, of course.)

There is ambiguity if you have more than one row with the same combination of `code` and either positive `qty` or `qty = 0`; exactly the same ambiguity you left open with your problem statement.

```
with
  inputs as (
    select 'R' code, 200 qty from dual union all
    select 'R'     ,   0     from dual union all
    select 'A'     , 100     from dual union all
    select 'A'     ,   0     from dual
  )
select   *
from     inputs
order by sign(qty) desc, code
;

CODE  QTY
---- ----
A     100
R     200
A       0
R       0
```